# How to add stylesheet dynamically in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-template

Is there a way to add stylesheet url or `<style></style>` dynamically in Angular2 ?

For example, if my variable is `isModalOpened` is `true`, I would like to add some CSS to few elements outside my root component. Like the `body` or `html`.

It's possible to do it with the DOM or jQuery but I would like to do this with Angular 2.

Possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at NgClass https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: @YakovFain In my case, I can not access to the body. So I can't add ng-class attribute to it.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `<style>` tag dynamically like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const css = 'a {color: pink;}';
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do it to body or html, but you can do it to root component.

- Create a service injected to root component
- Let the service have a state ( may be `BehaviorSubject` )
- Access that service and change the state when `isModalOpened` is changed
- In root component , you will be watching this and change component parameter values
- Inside root component html , you can change class values based on the component param values

**Update** : Setting background color from an inner component .

**`app.component.css`**

```
.red{
    background: red;
 }

.white{
    background: white;
 }
.green{
    background: green;
 }
```

**`app.component.html`**

```
<div  [ngClass]="backgroundColor" ></div>
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
constructor(private statusService: StatusService) {
    this.subscription = this.statusService.getColor()
    .subscribe(color => { this.backgroundColor = color; });
}
```

**`status.service.ts`**

```
private color = new Subject<any>();
public setColor(newColor){
    this.color.next(newColor);
}
public getColor(){
    return this.color.asObservable();
}
```

**`child.component.ts`**

```
export class ChildComponent {
    constructor(private statusService: StatusService) {}

    setColor(color:string){
      this.statusService.setColor(color);
    }
}
```

So whenever we call setColor and pass a color variable such as 'red', 'green' or 'white' the background of root component changes accordingly.

Comment: Can you put an example please ?

Comment: will create a plnkr

Answer (score 0):

Put all your  html code in a custom directive - let's call it ngstyle...

Add your ngstyle to your page using the directive tags, in our case:

```
<ngstyle><ngstyle>
```

but let's also append the logic to your directive using ng-if so you can toggle it on or off...

```
<ngstyle ng-if="!isModalOpened"><ngstyle>
```

Now if your 'isModalOpened' is set to a scope in your controller like this:

```
$scope.isModalOpened = false; //or true, depends on what you need
```

...you can toggle it true or false many different ways which should toggle your directive on and off.